# Modified Coin Change Problem with Infinite Coins of Denominations of Powers of 5

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, coin-change

We are given a set of denominations and a total amount.

- Infinite coins of each denomination are available
- All denominations are powers of 5

We have to find the minimum number of coins needed to make the total.

I wish to know the logic behind the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is just the sum of the total’s digits, base 5.

Answer (score 0):

If we denote the denominations as [w<sub>1</sub>, w<sub>2</sub> ... w<sub>n</sub>], such that w<sub>i</sub> = 5 × w<sub>i+1</sub>, then the denominations forms a [superincreasing sequence](https://oeis.org/wiki/Superincreasing_sequences). The page lists a general greedy algorithm if the denominations are powers of K, where K ≥ 2.

The proof is simple, if you remove a single coin of denomination w<sub>i</sub>, you would need at least 5 coins of lower denomination to get the same sum.